# UIView going back to design Offset when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I'm developing an iOS app in swift where I have two UIViews, one is visible the other is hidden, when I click on "Register" Button, the hidden UIView must take the place of the visible UIView. All is good, but when keyboard shows up the mess happens, what could be the reason? and how to fix it?!

The code I'm using to change offset is:

```
self.mRegisterContainer.frame = CGRectOffset( self.mlogin.frame, 0, 0 );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using storyboards and auto layout?

Comment: Yes I am, and I just disabled auto Layout and problem solved thank you so much @luk2302 if I may ask what is the relation between both? and when to use both together?

Comment: you should use storyboards with auto layout. you situation already needs storyboards: to create different, seperate views. you should not hide one view by placing off screen. present it using storyboard segues and all the related stuff. you need auto layout as soon as you target multiple screen sizes, therefore: you need it!

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 I switched to the proper way of using storyboards and made a new view for it in my storyboard file and now things are the way they suppose to.